# Color only border of rectangle

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way I can only color the borders of a rectangle and leave the inside of it white?
Similar to this one.

[image: Like this rectangle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use stroke and strokeWidth instead of fill.

See http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/#objects or the documentation for more information.